# How to Find & Replace a String Within Files with Find / Grep / Sed

Tags: sed, grep, find

I have a folder of 500 *.INI files that I need to manually edit. Within each INI file, I have the line `Source =`. I would like that line to become `Source = C:\software\{filename}`.

For instance, a dx4.ini file would need to be fixed to become: `Source = C:\software\dx4`

Is there a quick way to do this with Find, Grep, or Sed functions?

Comment: Please add what you've tried, if are completely new to all this, I'd suggest to go through https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/112023/how-can-i-replace-a-string-in-a-files and then ask a question here if you get stuck with the commands you've tried

Comment: This might help with `bash`: `for filename in *.INI; do base="${filename%*.INI}"; echo "$base $filename"; done`

Comment: Regarding your desire to edit the contents: don't.  Create a new directory and write new files with the data.  When the process is complete and verified, delete the old directory tree. Attempting to edit the files directly gains you absolutely nothing and introduces unnecessary risk of data corruption.

Answer (score 0):

You can try with sed
For example

Input file contents:
file.txt

```
Source =
some lines..
```

script:

```
newstring='Source = C:\software\dx4'
oldstring='Source ='
echo `sed "s/$oldstring/$newstring/g" file.txt` > file.txt
```

After running the above commands
output:

```
Source = C:\software\dx4
some lines..
```

Comment: I suggest to remove `echo` and both backticks.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to **ed**it a file in a script, I think `ed` is the way to go. Combined with a shell `for` loop:

```sh
for file in *.INI; do
    base=$(basename "$file" .INI)
    ed -s "$file" <<EOF
/^Source =/s/=/= C:\\\\software\\\\$base/
w
EOF
done
```

(This does assume that filenames will not have newlines or ampersands in their names)

Answer (score 0):

With GNU awk for the 3rd arg to match(), gensub(), and "inplace" editing:

```
awk -i inplace '
    match($0,/(.*Source = C:\\software\\){filename}(.*)/,a) {
        fname = gensub(/\..*/,"",1,FILENAME)
        $0 = a[1] fname a[2]
    }
1' *.INI
```

The above assumes you're running in a UNIX environment though your use of the term `folder` instead of `directory` and that path starting with `C:` and containing backslashes makes me suspicious. If you're on Windows then save the part between the 2 `'`s (exclusive) in a file named `foo.awk` and execute it as `awk -i inplace foo.awk *.INI` or however it is you normally execute commands like this in Windows.

Answer (score 0):

```
find *.ini -type -f > stack

while read line 
do
sed -i s"@Source =@Source = C:\\software\\dx4@" "${line}"
done < stack
```

Assuming that a} You have sed with "-i" (the insert flag, which AFAIK is not always portable) and b} sed doesn't crap itself about a double escape sequence, I think that will work.